# Power equipment for removing compacted gravel?

Tags: excavation

I have a gravel driveway in my front yard that I want to remove to put a garden bed. The gravel is large (1/2" to 1" dia.) and very compacted, so it is nearly impossible to remove by hand.

I want to rent some small power equipment to do the task, but I'm not sure if a skid loader, excavator, or something else is the right tool for the job. Opinions?

Comment: This is exactly what bulldozers have [ripper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulldozer#Ripper)s for. Perhaps there's a small, walk-behind earth mover with such a tool?

Comment: A tractor with a box scraper that has rippers would be the way I would do it. As you rip the box drags the rock to where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you don't want to remove a stitch of it. What you want to do is take advantage of what you've got & capitalize on the perfect setup for a perfect garden. A Raised Bed Garden on top is what this has been patiently waiting for. The gravel is key to keeping pests at bay & to relieve overwatering. This is why garden centers & nurseries have gravel all over & under...no yucky mud.

SEEEEE

[image: rAISED bED]

OOOOh

[image: Raised Bed]

AAAAAh

[image: raised bed]

Comment: Singularly unhelpful. My front yard doesn't look like a multi-million dollar xeriscaping job in Marin County. It looks like a slum lord dumped a truckload of ugly crushed gravel  so that 4+ people could park in my front yard. Cause that's what happened. Also my front yard is full shade.

Comment: So, you don't like raised beds & a raised bed won't work, but an in-ground garden will? I'm a bit confused. Do you want all of the gravel gone or just the area of the garden? I will happily update my answer.